# mouseover on an img, but mouseout on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little problems with mouseover and mouseout

I want to use mouseover when the user put his mouse in the image (id = calendrieragenda), but mouseout only when he leave the parent div (id = divagenda), but it's don't work, when the user leave his mouse from the image, it's activate the function mouseout

```js
var divagenda = document.getElementById('divagenda');
var calendrieragenda = document.getElementById('imageagenda');

calendrieragenda.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.getElementById('divagenda').className = 'popUpAgendaMouseOver';
});

divagenda.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      document.getElementById('divagenda').className = 'popUpAgendaMouseOut';

});
```

```css
#divagenda {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#imageagenda {
  width: 8%;
  position: relative;
  right: 6%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 600;
}

.popUpAgendaMouseOver {
  border-radius : 1em;
  border : 1px rgba(250, 250, 250, .8) solid;
  background-color: #444444;
  transition: 1s;
}

.popUpAgendaMouseOut {
  border : none;
  background-color:none;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="divagenda">
  <a href="link" title="Lien vers l'Agenda" target="_blank">
    <img id="imageagenda" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSf_HZLgiKNGwWv6V9Urtv3P2Sfo_Liw2dwOnq_oXg6-WInr_s" />
  </a>

</div>
```

I do a jsfiddle to show you my code : https://jsfiddle.net/v7pkhymm/7/

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that your event is bubbling from the img up so the div will also receive that event.

There are a couple way to prevent this. You could add an event listener at the calendrieragenda level to stopPropagation:

```
calendrieragenda.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Or you could check on the divagenda event listener that the target of the event is really the div:

```
divagenda.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.target !== this) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('divagenda').className = 'popUpAgendaMouseOut';

});
```

I would prefer the second method as it does not create an unnecessary event listener.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I use the second method and it's work !

Comment: I wonder why event.stopPropagation() does not work. The second one works though

Comment: Does it work for you in that link ? It works for me https://jsfiddle.net/v7pkhymm/9/

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to use `mouseleave` to avoid the bubble.

## Suggestions

- Use the `classList` collection to add and remove classes.
- Use the already found element `divagenda` to avoid repeated `getElementById` calls.

```js
var divagenda = document.getElementById('divagenda');
var calendrieragenda = document.getElementById('imageagenda');

calendrieragenda.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  divagenda.classList.add('popUpAgendaMouseOver');
});

divagenda.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    this.classList.remove('popUpAgendaMouseOver');
    this.classList.add('popUpAgendaMouseOut');
});
```

```css
#divagenda {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#imageagenda {
  width: 8%;
  position: relative;
  right: 6%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 600;
}

.popUpAgendaMouseOver {
  border-radius : 1em;
  border : 1px rgba(250, 250, 250, .8) solid;
  background-color: #444444;
  transition: 1s;
}

.popUpAgendaMouseOut {
  border : none;
  background-color:none;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="divagenda">
  <a href="link" title="Lien vers l'Agenda" target="_blank">
    <img id="imageagenda" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSf_HZLgiKNGwWv6V9Urtv3P2Sfo_Liw2dwOnq_oXg6-WInr_s" />
  </a>

</div>
```

## Resource

- [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)